# How do I parse numbers in a string?

Tags: java, string, integer, parseint

I have a string 'line' in java containing numbers , for example , "34 55  64 "

I want to store these 3 numbers in  `int x , y ,z`

when I do ,

```
x = Integer.parseInt(line[0]) 

y = Integer.parseInt(line[1])
```

I get an error saying a "array required but string found " . I do not understand why it needs an array

`x,y,z` are declared integers and line is declared as a string

Comment: Because you are specifying the __index__.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because a question is no substitute for reading the basics of programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("34 55 64");
x = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
y = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
z = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
```

As pointed out in comments, StringTokenizer is a legacy class (Not deprecated though) and can be replaced with the following code

```
String line = "34 55 64 ";
String []splits = line.trim().split("\\s+");
x = Integer.parseInt(splits[0]);
y = Integer.parseInt(splits[1]);
z = Integer.parseInt(splits[2]);
```

Comment: Note the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) says _StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code_

Answer (score 3):

First split the string into array for the spaces(`\\s+`):

```
String line = "34 55 64 ";
String []splits = line.trim().split("\\s+");
```

Then perform `Integer.parseInt(splits[0])`

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do such thing? This is a very specific code and will work in a very limited inputs whichmakes the ccode very fragile.  Anyhow,  splitting the string to string array first as Sabuj suggested sounds like the best option for such requirement